Can't import matplotlib in jupyter notebook
I have Python 3.9 in a virtual environment on my work PC. When I start the virtual environment with source ./python3.9_venv/bin/activate and then launch a python terminal with the command python3 , I am able to import matplotlib just fine, e.g, the command import matplotlib.pyplot runs with no errors. I am using the latest version of Numpy, version 2.0.2
However, when I launch a Jupyter Notebook, I get the error message
A module that was compiled using NumPy 1.x cannot be run in
NumPy 2.0.2 as it may crash. To support both 1.x and 2.x
versions of NumPy, modules must be compiled with NumPy 2.0.
Some module may need to rebuild instead e.g. with 'pybind11>=2.12'.

If you are a user of the module, the easiest solution will be to
downgrade to 'numpy<2' or try to upgrade the affected module.
We expect that some modules will need time to support NumPy 2.

Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/usr/people/shared/tools/centos/7/python/3.9.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
..........

/usr/people/shared/tools/centos/7/python/3.9.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py in <module>
     44 
     45 from matplotlib import _api
---> 46 from matplotlib._path import (
     47     affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox, update_path_extents)
     48 from .path import Path

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

I tried downgrading my Numpy version to 1.26.0 using the command pip3 install --force-reinstall numpy=="1.26.0" and restarting my Jupyter kernel, but it seems to have no effect. It appears Jupyter Notebooks always use the latest version of Numpy, i.e if I run the command numpy.__version__ it always prints 2.0.2 regardless of the version of numpy I have installed on my system.
The operating system I am using is rather old - Centos 7. I don't know if this could be causing problems. I don't have the expertise to say for sure.
Hope someone can help.

The traceback seems to show that the Matplotlib that gets imported is not in your virtual environment but a sitewide copy.  Do you have Jupyter Notebook installed in your virtual environment and do you activate the virtual environment before launching Jupyter Notebook?

@RuthC Good observation. Yes, I do activate the virtual environment using source ./python3.9_venv/bin/activate before I carry on. However, it appears I don't have Jupyter installed on it, i.e, find python3.9_venv/ -iname "jupyter" produces nothing. I am launching Jupyter notebook using jupyter notebook --ip=$(hostname -i) so I thought this forced it to use my local installation but, apparently not....
